# Can Win10's defender prompt user before taking actions

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

When updated to Win10, I choose to use its built-in Defender as my antivirus software, It works well ,but when finding virus, it directly quarantine or delete files without any alert to users, so my question is

Can win10's defender prompt user before taking actions like other third party antivirus software

for example, show a dialog to say it found some virus files, user can choose to delete them or just ignore the information, Can it be configured to meet this goal

Thanks for any suggestions!

ps: if impossible to deal with files detected by user, Is there a way to let user know what actions be taken right after it occurred(rather than user mannually go to control panel to see which files have been quarantined)

Comment: Windows Defender doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thanks for reply, I updated questions,Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting in Windows Defender that gives the option to prompt the user to select from a list of possible options when a virus or other malware is detected.

You can review the scan logs and you can whitelist files and directories, but these are done manually, and likely after an unwanted detection occurs.

When I open Windows Defender on my computer, go into Virus and Threat Protection, there's a pretty clear section toward the bottom labeled "Notifications" wherein I find a variety of options for the application informing you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then Is there a way to let user know what actions be taken right after it occurred(rather than user mannually go to control panel to see which files have been quarantined)

Comment: @J1B - No; There isn’t;